# Setting cookies programmatically for each response in flask

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I am not able to find documentation on this. I know flask has support for cookies. But I don't want to use it. That is because I want to determine the format of the cookie and I want to encrypt it as well. The default option in flask is to have the cookie be a random string and then optionally sign it. But I want to do more.

I am looking for a way to create a new cookie and set the value of the cookie for the flask engine to use in the response.

Comment: Are you talking about session cookie? Look at this [article](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/51/) about flask session cookies. You always can override flask cookies handling using [flask.session_interface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.session_interface).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use flasks session cookie, or override its behavior like suggested by @Ostrovski (nice find by the way!) you can set cookies manually using a response object. Check this out...

```
@app.route('/cookie-monster')
def cookie_monster():
    # Create a response object and set a cookie
    r = Response(render_template('my_template.html'))
    r.set_cookie('cookie_name',value='values')

    return r
```

You can find more about this right over here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/30/

Good luck!

Comment: I'm afraid, that it won't help if we are talking about overriding session cookie. Flask sets session cookie after calling a view function. And even after calling all `after_request` hooks.

Comment: @Ostrovski I may have misunderstood the question, it looked as though he wanted to ditch flasks session cookie and set up his own entirely.

Comment: But your answer doesn't override any session cookie. You only set a custom cookie named `cookie_name`. Also you are using the `Response` class directly and it doesn't look like a good practice. I suggest to use `make_request()` instead.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, I may have misunderstood the question. I maintain it appears he *doesn't want to use the built in session cookie* and wants to *create a new cookie* with a custom value. You are correct though, make_request is the more accepted method of generating response objects.